# Preg_Replace() Array with Symbols

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, preg-replace

I am extracting data from lengthy XML documents using `foreach` loops and `if statements`. After successfully extracting the data I am formatting it, primarily using `preg_replace` as a lot of the data is stored as an abbreviation while I need the full word or phrase. I have been successful in creating a `preg_replace` array which includes all my desired replacements. However, I am struggling with abbreviations such as `w/`. I want `w/` to be replaced with `with` and `w/OD` with `with overdrive`. Below is my code and output.

***My php:***

```
<?php

$patterns = [
 '/\b(pwr|pwer)\b/i' => 'Power',
 '/CVT/' => 'Automatic',
 '/@/' => 'at',

];

echo "<i>All Tech Specs:</i>.<br><br>";

 foreach ($finaltitle as $titlenumber => $titlename){
   foreach ($techData as $tsnumber => $tsname){
     if ($tsnumber == $titlenumber){
       if(empty($tsname) or $tsname === '- TBD -' or $tsname ==='N/A') continue;
         $tsname =  preg_replace(array_keys($patterns), $patterns, $tsname);
           $finaltsdata = "<b>".$titlename." (".$tsnumber.") "."</b>: ".$tsname."<br>";

    echo $finaltsdata;
   }
  }
 }

?>
```

***Output:***

```
Vehicle Name (1) : Toyota Corolla
Body Style (2) : Sedan
Drivetrain (6) : Front Wheel Drive
EPA Classification (7) : Compact Cars
Passenger Capacity (8) : 5
Passenger Volume (9) : 97.5
Base Curb Weight (10) : 2840
Engine Type (41) : Regular Unleaded I-4
Displacement (42) : 1.8 L/110
Fuel System (43) : Sequential MPI
SAE Net Horsepower @ RPM (48) : 132 at 6000
SAE Net Torque @ RPM (49) : 128 at 4400
Trans Type (52) : 1
Trans Description Cont. (53) : Automatic w/OD
```

If I add `'/w//' => 'with',` to my `$patterns` array, I get an error due to the inclusion of `/`. Any ideas on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may use `'~w/~' => 'with'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works excellently! Thank you